# printf, redirection, crontab

Tags: command-line, cron, redirect, stdout

I'm having trouble redirecting C printf statements to a file with a program running as root.

I have a program with several informational printf statements and other libraries which print errors via stderr.  I'd like to log these to a file.  If I start the program from the command line, I can see stderr and stdout messages.

```
sudo ./myprogram
```

If I try to redirect like so,

```
sudo ./myprogram >> log_file 2>&1
```

The log_file only contains stderr, and stdout disappears.

I suspect the issue is related to the root user not being connected to stdout, but I haven't found a solution.

My ultimate goal is to run this program at system start as root, while logging stderr and stdout to a log_file.
I've been trying this using crontab,

```
 sudo crontab -e
```

and adding the line,

```
@reboot bin/myprogram >> log_file 2>&1
```

This generates stderr messages but stdout disappears, same as command line.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edits & updates:
Testing this morning, the redirection behaves the same without sudo.
A typical printf statement looks like:

```
printf("info: passed safety check\n");
```

I'm using a default set up for ubuntu 14.04 on an ARM processor, so I believe I'm using bash.  I confirmed with,

```
echo $SHELL
```

produces

```
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Does it work without `sudo`? Could you share a line of code that contains a `printf` statement?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash` with `sudo` and `cron`? There are shells which do not understand this redirection syntax. And you could have different shells set up in these different contexts.

Comment: May be only `stderr` generate nothing to output by `stdout`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The behaviour of `printf()` seems to depend on the location of
>   `stdout`.
>
> 1. If `stdout` is sent to the console, then `printf()` is line-buffered and is flushed after a newline is printed.
> 2. If `stdout` is redirected to a file, the buffer is not flushed unless `fflush()` is called.
> 3. Moreover, if `printf()` is used before `stdout` is redirected to file, subsequent writes (to the file) are line-buffered and are
>      flushed after newline.

**Source: [Why does stdout need explicit flushing when redirected to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932932/why-does-stdout-need-explicit-flushing-when-redirected-to-file)**

I'm not well versed with C programming, but apparently you need to add `fflush(stdout);` after every `printf` statement. Try it out from the command line. If it works, it should work with cron.

More questions on this topic:

- [C stdout printf problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605680/c-stdout-printf-problem)
- [Problem redirecting a C program output in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499879/problem-redirecting-a-c-program-output-in-bash)

Comment: Yep, adding `fflush(stdout);` after printf statements captures stdout and stderr messages.  Tested using `sudo ./myprogram &> log_file` (it works as non-root as well).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [TLDP HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) has this nice syntax for redirection of both `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
  @reboot /path/to/program &> /path/to/log
```

The HowTo says that it's sometimes suitable for cron entries.

Comment: Cron doesn't have @redirect, I tried this. `@reboot /path/to/program &> /path/to/log` and it produced stderr in the log, but no stdout

Comment: @user2977486 does the reverse redirection help? First stderr to file, then stdin to err? `2>log 1>&2`?

Comment: same result, this produces error messages but no printf messages in the log

Comment: @user2977486 And just redirection of stdout, leaving stderr untouched?